# PHP PRINTER EROR

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, php-printer

Good day everyone please help me to solved this code. I want to print all value of an array in php printer but only 1 only display. Im using php codeigniter framework 3. thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs24z.jpg)
Output:
Qty Description
1   Product One

```
$content = "Customer " . $this->uri->segment(2) . "\n"; 
foreach ($orders as $order) { 
    $content = "Qty Description\r" . $order->Quan . " " . 
              " " . " " . $order->Description . "\r"; 
} 
$printer = ("EPSON TM-U220 Receipt"); 
$handler = printer_open($printer); 
if($handler) { 
} 
else { 
    echo "not connected"; 
} 
printer_write($handler, $content); 
printer_close($handler);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add your code there as text. It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: Your `if($handler) { ` code should either include the `printer_write()` parts or stop if the printer fails to connect.  At the moment it will display a message and then just carry on and try printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to concatenate `$content`.

Change

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
   $content = ....
}
```

to

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
   $content .= ....   // here-> .= 
}
```

Comment: it is posible to print data in 2 printers at the same time?

Comment: _it is posible to print data in 2 printers..._ Inever tried that, but I think you'll need 2 separate handlers

Comment: using condition statement right?

Comment: Just something like `$handler1 = printer_open($printer1);$handler2 = printer_open($printer2)` etc

Comment: mate have you tried printing using network connection?

Comment: Ah no sorry, but there must be some good tutorials out there

Comment: mate what's wrong to my code please help me

Comment: printer_draw_text($handle, "CUSTOMER " . $this->uri->segment(2)."", 10, 10);
printer_draw_text($handle, "". $record->Pax . "PAX", 10, 10);
printer_draw_text($handle, "" . $date_time . "", 10, 10);
foreach ($orders as $order) {
        printer_draw_text($handle, "" . $order->Quan . " " . strtoupper($order->Description). "", 10, 10);
        if (!empty($order->Remarks) || $order->Remarks != "") {
             printer_draw_text($handle,"" . strtoupper($order->Remarks) . "");
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of `$content` until the `foreach()` loop ends.So for now it's only displaying the last value that was assigned to $content inside the `foreach()` loop.

There are two things that you can do basically.

1.Assign the values into an array.

```
foreach($orders as $order) {    
$content[] = "Qty Description\r" . $order->Quan . " " . " " . " " . $order->Description . "\r";
}
```

By this method all the values that you are getting from the loop will be stored inside the array.

2.concatenate the values in `$content`

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
     $content .= "Qty Description\r" . $order->Quan . " " . " " . " " . $order->Description . "\r";
  }
```

I hope this will help you.